# different pages in different files in react native

Tags: react-native

I am totally new to react native and I am just wondering if I am misunderstanding something when it comes to different pages in it.

I am just playing with it at the moment but everything is in the app.js folder. Is there a way to put the single pages into different files like

main.js
about.js, etc

I have made a very simple app with a navigation menu at the bottom and it shows the pages in functions. I would like these functions in single files.

Is it just the way it's designed or am I just not getting it? It would make things a lot easier.

My simple code in app.js is:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

function Search() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <Text>Hello</Text>
      </View>
    );
}

function Notifications() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <Text>Notifications!</Text>
      </View>
    );
}

function Messages() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <Text>Messages!</Text>
      </View>
    );
}

function Location() {
    return (
      <WebView
        style={styles.container}
        source={{ uri: 'https://www.google.com' }}
      />
    );
}

function Profile() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <Text>User Profile!</Text>
      </View>
    );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function MyTabs() {
    return (
      <Tab.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Location"
        screenOptions={{
            tabBarActiveTintColor: '#e91e63',
        }}
      >
          <Tab.Screen
            name="Search"
            component={Search}
            options={{
                tabBarLabel: 'Search',
                tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                  <MaterialCommunityIcons name="account-search" color={color} size={size} />
                ),
            }}
          />

          <Tab.Screen
            name="Notifications"
            component={Notifications}
            options={{
                tabBarLabel: 'Notification',
                tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                  <MaterialCommunityIcons name="bell" color={color} size={size} />
                ),
            }}
          />
          <Tab.Screen
            name="Messages"
            component={Profile}
            options={{
                tabBarLabel: 'Messages',
                tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                  <MaterialCommunityIcons name="message" color={color} size={size} />
                ),
            }}
          />

          <Tab.Screen
            name="Locationddsd"
            component={Location}
            options={{
                tabBarLabel: 'Location',
                tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                  <MaterialCommunityIcons name="map-marker" color={color} size={size} />
                ),
            }}
          />

          <Tab.Screen
            name="Profile"
            component={Profile}
            options={{
                tabBarLabel: 'Account',
                tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                  <MaterialCommunityIcons name="account" color={color} size={size} />
                ),
            }}
          />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        marginTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    },
});

export default function App() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
          <MyTabs />
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```

I am not asking for help coding just advice on adding them into separate files and calling them.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I found a good example here if anyone needs it

https://snack.expo.dev/@aboutreact/bottom-navigation-example

Comment: It's crazy how even in 2023 almost ALL tutorials you come across just have everything in a single App.js with no mention on how to do this!